# How to free a malloc 2D array in C initialiszed in this way?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, heap-memory, free

I have declared a 2D malloc array like this in C:

```
    int** pArray;
    int i;

    pArray=(int**)malloc(pRows*sizeof(int*));
       for(i=0;i<pRows;i++)
         (int*)malloc(pColumns*sizeof(int*));
```

How can I free this array? I saw on the net that the number of free() should be same as number of malloc() used. What can I free twice in this case?

Comment: You're not assigning the results of the mallocs in the loop anywhere. You can't free them if there's no variables holding the pointers. You need `pArray[i] = malloc(...);`.

Comment: `What can I free twice in this case?` What? You don't free things twice.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Once you fix that problem, you just free everything in reverse. Loop over the array freeing each element, then free `pArray`.

Comment: The inner loop should be `malloc(pColumns*sizeof(int));` (one acceptable method). You `malloc` space for the thing you're pointing to, which inside the loop is `int` type, not `int*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the allocation is incorrect. This statement

```
(int*)malloc(pColumns*sizeof(int*));
```

produces a memory leak.

It seems you mean the following code

```
int** pArray;
int i;

pArray = (int**)malloc( pRows * sizeof( int* ) );
for( i = 0; i < pRows; i++ )
{
     pArray[i] = (int*)malloc( pColumns * sizeof( int ) );
}
```

Pay attention to that in the statement within the loop there is used the expression `sizeof( int )` instead of `sizeof( int * )`.

You need to free the allocated memory in the reverse order

```
for( i = 0; i < pRows; i++ )
{
     free( pArray[i] );
}
free( pArray );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me

Comment: Also, is there also a way to use malloc without causing any memory leaks in the first place?

Comment: @Kalindu It is you who is responsible to free the allocated memory to prevent a memory leak.